# How can I sort data from three datasets? (SSRS 2008)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I can't find solution how can I sort data form three datasets. I have one static dataset and two matrix tables which I want to connect in one report. Every table has the same ID which I can use to connect them (the same number of rows as well) but don't know how could I do this? Is it  possibile to connect few datasets?

table1:

```
N   ID  St  From    To  
1   541 7727549         08:30:00    14:00:00  
2   631 7727575         07:00:00    15:00:00  
3   668 7727552         09:00:00    17:00:00  
4   679     18:00:00    00:00:00  
5   721     17:00:00    00:00:00
```

table:2

```
ID  P1  P2  P3  P4  
541 12:00:00 - 12:10:00         
631 08:45:00 - 08:55:00 11:30:00 - 11:40:00 13:00:00 - 13:15:00   
668 12:05:00 - 12:15:00 13:45:00 - 13:55:00 14:55:00 - 15:10:00   
679 21:15:00 - 21:30:00           
721 20:40:00 - 20:50:00 21:50:00 - 22:05:00
```

table3:

```
ID  W1  W2  W3  
541 11:28:58 - 11:39:13         
631 08:46:54 - 08:58:43 11:07:04 - 11:17:05     
668 11:26:11 - 11:41:44     
679           
721 11:07:19 - 11:17:06
```

Comment: Can you show examples of what your tables look like, and what you're aiming to achieve with the report?

Comment: I've just added examples of table but please be patient, later I'll edit them to normal view, have no time right now:)